# How do I make my query more precise based on my condition to return a string to check duplicate record exist

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am creating string function which checks duplicate record before **inserting or updating** a record but I have a condition with it. Before giving conditions, I have a table called Products (name, description, type, isActive, InsertedDate, UpdatedDate). Isenabled is in bit datatype (0 or 1). And InsertedDate, UpdatedDate are auto generated.

In isActive column

0 means disable 
1 means enable

Before inserting (or even updating), check whether name is unique but if name exist more than one then,

My conditions

1. Check whether product is isActive = 1 then while inserting data should display message "Product exist in the table."
2. Check whether product is isActive = 0  then while inserting data should display message "Product exist but it is disabled."
3. Else Insert/Update the data.

Below function only check whether record exist or not and return message accordingly.

Question: How can I have return proper message regardless I am checking above query for inserting or updating a record and it goes over my requirement. As Top 1 can help me to insert new record checking if name is unique and it will return empty but if I am updating row with its own keeping name as it is and changing other column which is  description. And when I update that I am receiving message "Record exist in the table" which it should not give me and should updating without message.  So how can I make this query check for both the method **inserting and updating** record.

**Here is what I have tried:**

```
private string GetName(string name, int id)
{
        using (var connection = connection string)
        using (var command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText =
            @"DECLARE @Enabled INT; " +
            @"SET @Enabled = " +
            @"( " +
                @"SELECT TOP 2 p.isActive " +
                @"FROM dbo.[product] p WITH (nolock) " +
                @"WHERE p.name = @name " +
            @"); " +
            @"SELECT Msg = CONVERT( VARCHAR(32), " +
                                             @"CASE " +
                                                 @"WHEN @Enabled = 0 " +
                                                 @"THEN 'Record is disabled' " +
                                                 @"WHEN @Enabled = 2 " +
                                                 @"THEN 'Record exist in the table' " +
                                                 @"ELSE ''";
                                             @"END);";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", name);
            command.CommandTimeout = 100;
            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            string message = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
            connection.Close();
            return message;
        }
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

**Note** My query might be wrong. If you do not understand my query then please go over to what I am doing before inserting or updating record and accordingly I am expecting to have a query. Also please don't worry about Insert or update query I have a different method which takes care of it. Also if you have any solution which can help me to solve my probkem ten I would really appreciate that.

Summery

1. First check duplicate record exist or not (Means check all names are unique).
2. If name exist more than 1 then check isActive is 0 or 1 and accordingly sends the message which I am showing in my query.

FYI: I know I can do it in Stored Procedure but this is like a requirement to do it with command parameter.

Also if you guys think tha this post does not have consistant, please let me know instead of downgrading or flagging it.

Comment: Why do you do `SELECT TOP 2 p.isActive` instead of just `SELECT COUNT(*)` or `SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT p.isActive)`?

Comment: Disregard previous idea, why not `SELECT TOP 1 p.isActive ... order by p.isActive DESC`? I haven't tried it but I suspect this might give you distinct `NULL`, `TRUE` and `FALSE`

Comment: Also, why should the message be in the query? It would be cleaner to use one of the above queries to get the data from the DB and choose the message in code.

Comment: @SergGr Top 1 always select 1 row. So for instance if I am updating a row changing only description and Name will be as it is then it will return Record exist in the table and will not update the table.

Comment: @JayZ96, how `SELECT TOP 1` might return 1 row if there is no matching rows in the table at all? I expect it to return NULL in such case and if there is a row, to return its `IsActive` value

Comment: @SergGr I tried updating a record with top 1 and when I update. For example, I am updating row 5 with its own keeping name as it is and changing other column  description. And when I update that I am receiving message "Record exist in the table" which it should not give me and should updating without message.

Comment: `TOP` for `UPDATE` and `TOP` for `SELECT` work similarly but differently. Still your question doesn't mention any `update top` queries at all so I'm confused what are you talking about.

Comment: Please read my first line I have mentioned "I am creating string function which checks duplicate record before **inserting or updating a record**". So this function only checks unique name and my other condition with it. regardless whether it checks for inserting or updating records.

Comment: @JayZ96 I still don't get it. Your question now says `Question: I am unable to return message "Record exist in the table". I know my query is wrong but how can I make this query proper in which it returns message based on my condition listed above?` I made a suggestion of how to make an SQL that answers that paqrticular question. If you have some other questions, state them explicitly in the text.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I have updated the question in my post. Hope that will remove your confusion and understand what am I expecting.

Comment: I think you're going about this the wrong way.  You should attempt to insert the record and let the usual database constraints handle the duplicate detection.  If the insertion fails, run another query to detect the data conditions you want to display in your error message.   Much simpler.

Comment: I don't know about query detecting data conditions part which you have added. .But I have added constraints to have unique name. When user clicks on insert data or updte data . First above function runs then it does is inserting or updateing data